# Is the nervous message sent by an eyelash being flexed sent all the way to the brain?

Tags: muscles, eyes, neuron, reflexes

Since the reflex to close the eyelid once an eyelash is touched seems very fast, does the signal from the neuron detecting the touching travel all the way to the brain, get processed then back to the eyelid muscle?
Or does it have some kind of bypass that activates the eyelid muscle right away as some sort of reflex mechanism?

Comment: I don't think any reflex is controlled by the brain. Then again, I guess it might not be the case for something near the eyes since other reflexes tend to go through the spine's grey matter and the eyelashes obviously don't.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.